# Parsing rest XML response and find specific entity in java

Tags: java

I am new to RestAPI hence need help in parsing rest XML response and find specific entity in java.

From Below response I am looking for `<objectId>virtualwire-3560</objectId>` where this can be multiple entry in the response.

```
<virtualWires>
<dataPage>
<pagingInfo>
   <pageSize>10</pageSize>
   <startIndex>0</startIndex>
   <totalCount>4660</totalCount>
   <sortOrderAscending>true</sortOrderAscending>
</pagingInfo>
<virtualWire>
<objectId>virtualwire-3560</objectId>
<objectTypeName>VirtualWire</objectTypeName>
<vsmUuid>420BCD52-2C18-7300-BC69-B8E92908084D</vsmUuid>
<nodeId>cf73616c-1fde-40a8-896f-c4f8e4270972</nodeId>
<revision>1</revision>
<type>
```

Comment: <virtualWires>
   <dataPage>
      <pagingInfo>
         <pageSize>10</pageSize>
         <startIndex>0</startIndex>
         <totalCount>4660</totalCount>
         <sortOrderAscending>true</sortOrderAscending>
      </pagingInfo>
      <virtualWire>
         <objectId>virtualwire-3560</objectId>
         <objectTypeName>VirtualWire</objectTypeName>
         <vsmUuid>420BCD52-2C18-7300-BC69-B8E92908084D</vsmUuid>
         <nodeId>cf73616c-1fde-40a8-896f-c4f8e4270972</nodeId>
         <revision>1</revision>
         <type>

Comment: Look into using XPath.

Comment: I am looking for virtualwire-3560 where this can be multiple times under tag in the response

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You're developing a client application and getting this xml as a response to your request?

Comment: yes Dainu I am getting the response.